# get function name or some unique id of function from object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
window.VO = {}; 
window.viewObjects = function (viewName, view) {
    if (viewName in VO)
    {
        console.log('unbinding');
        VO[viewName].undelegateEvents();
    }
    VO[viewName] = view;
    return view;
};
```

I wrote the above function to deal with the multiple rendering of same view.

But now I need to pass a unique name for each view.

```
window.viewObjects('BooksIndex', new Views.Dashboard.Books.Index());
```

Is there a way I can avoid the argument viewName?

any way to get the name of the function from view object.

but another issue is when we have views like

```
Dashboard.Books.index()
Dashboard.Stores.index()
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the clean way if doing, what is your use case?

Answer (score 0):

All the Backbone views have a `cid` (client id) that is unique. You could use this id to identify the views instead of assigning a different name.

Something like this:

```
window.VO = {}; 
window.viewObjects = function (view) {
    if (view.cid in VO)
    {
        console.log('unbinding');
        VO[view.cid].undelegateEvents();
    }
    VO[view.cid] = view;
    return view;
};
```

The relevant part extracted from the [Backbone annotated code](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-153) where a new unique `cid` is set on View creation:

```
var View = Backbone.View = function(options) {
    this.cid = _.uniqueId('view');
    options || (options = {});
    _.extend(this, _.pick(options, viewOptions));
    this._ensureElement();
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  };
```

Comment: But cid is created when ever the view is initialized, so its not same for all the views objects, My intention is to undelegate all the events of the existing view if a new view object is initialized